# Lyft renewal token not working

Tags: authentication, access-token

Has anyone successfully renewed access token?

Lyft document suggest that we pass renew_token with renew_token request. but there is no API to receive the renew_token. Asking user to everytime grant an access is not a practical way to implement OAuth.

https://developer.lyft.com/docs/authentication

This is the link for to lyft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got this working, but just to confirm the example from the docs just works

https://developer.lyft.com/docs/authentication

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --user "<client_id>:<client_secret>" \
     -d '{"grant_type": "refresh_token", "refresh_token": <refresh_token>}' \
     'https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token'
```

The response comes back with a new access_token

```
{"token_type": "Bearer", "access_token": "XXX", "expires_in": 3600, "scope": "profile offline rides.read public rides.request"}
```